# Repeated column names in prepared statement and execution

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, prepared-statement

`$_POST['data']` contains an `id` and other fields that need to be inserted in a DB row with this `id`.

Is there a way to avoid redundancy in this code:

```
$data =  json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
$db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET a=?, b=?, c=?, d=?, e=?, f=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($data['a'], $data['b'], $data['c'], $data['d'], $data['e'], $data['f'], $data['id']));
```

How to avoid to repeat the column names `a`, ..., `f` twice, once in the prepared statement, and once in the array?

Can we totally avoid to hardcode the column names `a`, ..., `f`, and just infer them from the `$data` array keys?

Comment: You can write a function that takes a dictionary as the argument, and constructs the SQL dynamically from the dictionary keys.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. Maybe you should use an ORM.

Comment: _"and just infer them from the $data array keys?"_ Yes you can do that. Should you? Depends if you trust the input. If you only want to update columns a through f but you write a generic query builder, then your API users will be able to update any column just by including them in the JSON.

Comment: @Barmar Without writing my own "helper" util functions or using an ORM, is the current code in my question the shortest we can have with built-in functions?

Comment: As I said, there's nothing built-in that does it more easily.

Comment: @Barmar Then this is probably the answer, if you post it, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a little easier by using named placeholders rather than `?`. Then you can just pass `$data` as the argument to `execute()`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE test SET a=:a, b=:b, c=B, d=:d, e=:e, f=:f WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->execute($data);
```

This just moves the redundancy from the `execute()` parameter to the placeholders. But it's less verbose.